# Powershell and regex to extract multiple points of data from a file

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to extra multiple points of data (First, Last, ID number) from a rather nasty log file.

I have this:

```
Get-Content c:\LOG\22JAN01.log | Out-String | 
  % {[Regex]::Matches($_, "(?<=FIRST:)((.|\n)*?)(?=LAST:)")} | % {$_.Value}
```

Which does a fine job of extracting the first name - but I need to also get the last name and ID number from the same line and present them together "BOB SMITH 123456"

Each line of the log file looks like this:

> FIRST:BOB LAST:SMITH DOOR:MAIN ENTRANCE ID:123456 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:47 PM INCIDENT:19002304

I would like the output to look something like:

- BOB SMITH 123456
- JACK JONES 029506
- KAREN KARPENTER 6890298

So far I can only manage to get all the first names and nothing else. Thanks for any help pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The log file does look as literally as what we see in the quoted text? Name, Last and door on the same line?

Answer (score 6):

If they are always on the same line, I like to use switch to read it.

```
switch -Regex -File c:\LOG\22JAN01.log {
    'FIRST:(\w+) LAST:(.+) DOOR.+ ID:(\d+) ' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            First = $matches[1]
            Last  = $matches[2]
            ID    = $matches[3]
        }
    }
}
```

Sample log output

```
First Last      ID     
----- ----      --     
BOB   SMITH     123456 
JACK  JONES     029506 
KAREN KARPENTER 6890298
```

You can capture it to a variable and then continue using the objects however you like.

```
$output = switch -Regex -File c:\LOG\22JAN01.log {
    'FIRST:(\w+) LAST:(.+) DOOR.+ ID:(\d+) ' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            First = $matches[1]
            Last  = $matches[2]
            ID    = $matches[3]
        }
    }
}

$output | Out-GridView

$output | Export-Csv -Path c:\Log\parsed_log.log -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capture groups `()`.

Assuming that `FIRST` is always right at the start of the line (remove the `^` if not), and that the field names are always present and in the same order, and that their values are at least one character long, you could use, for example:

```
$result = & {
  $path = "c:\LOG\22JAN01.log";
  $pattern = "^FIRST:(.+?) LAST:(.+?) DOOR:.+? ID:(\d+)";
  Select-String -Path $path -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches |
  % {$_.Matches.Groups[1], $_.Matches.Groups[2], $_.Matches.Groups[3] -join " "}
}
```

`.+?` means match one or more of any character except newlines, as few times as possible before what follows in the pattern can be matched. Something more restrictive such as `[A-Z]+` can be used instead if that will definitely match the required values.

Answer (score 2):

*If* you can make the assumption that each *field name* is composed of (English) *letters only*,<sup>[1]</sup> such as `FIRST`, **a generic solution that combines the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) with the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) cmdlet** is possible:

```sh
# Sample array of input lines.
$inputLines = 
  'FIRST:BOB LAST:SMITH DOOR:MAIN ENTRANCE ID:123456 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:47 PM INCIDENT:19002304',
  'FIRST:JACK LAST:JONES DOOR:SIDE ENTRANCE ID:123457 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:48 PM INCIDENT:19002305',
  'FIRST:KAREN LAST:KARPENTER DOOR:BACK ENTRANCE ID:123458 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:49 PM INCIDENT:19002306'

$inputLines -replace '\b([a-z]+):', "`n`$1=" | 
  ConvertFrom-StringData |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FIRST, $_.LAST, $_.ID -join ' ' }
```

- For each input line, the `-replace` operation places each field name-value pair onto its own line, replacing the separator, `:`, with `=`.
- The resulting block of lines is parsed by `ConvertFrom-StringData` into a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) representing the fields of each input line, allowing convenient access to the fields by name, e.g. `.FIRST` (PowerShell allows you to use *property-access syntax* as an alternative to *index* syntax, s.g. `['FIRST']`).

Output:

```
BOB SMITH 123456
JACK JONES 123457
KAREN KARPENTER 123458
```

---

<sup>[1] More generally, you can use this approach as long as you can formulate a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) that unambiguously identifies a field name.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the log file looks literally as what we see in the quoted text you could match it like this:

```
$log = @'
FIRST:BOB LAST:SMITH DOOR:MAIN ENTRANCE ID:123456 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:47 PM INCIDENT:19002304
FIRST:JOHN LAST:DOE DOOR:MAIN ENTRANCE ID:789101 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:47 PM INCIDENT:19002304
'@

$re = [regex]'(?si)FIRST:(?<first>.*?)\s*LAST:(?<last>.*?)\s*DOOR.*?ID:(?<id>\d+)'

foreach($match in $re.Matches($log))
{
    '{0} {1} {2}' -f
        $match.Groups['first'].Value,
        $match.Groups['last'].Value,
        $match.Groups['id'].Value
}

# Results in:
BOB SMITH 123456
JOHN DOE 789101
```

This regex should work on a *multi-line string* so you would use `-Raw` for [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$re = [regex]'(?si)FIRST:(?<first>.*?)\s*LAST:(?<last>.*?)\s*DOOR.*?ID:(?<id>\d+)'

$result = foreach($match in $re.Matches((Get-Content ./test.log -Raw)))
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        First = $match.Groups['first'].Value
        Last  = $match.Groups['last'].Value
        ID    = $match.Groups['id'].Value
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv path/to/newlog.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

See https://regex101.com/r/WluWpD/1 for the *regex* explanation.

Comment: The value of `DOOR` in the example is `MAIN ENTRANCE`, so `ENTRANCE` should not be in your regex as other doors may not include it. Also, the `.*?` at the end is pointless. Looks good otherwise.

Comment: @MikeM I'm dumb, thank you! for both things (`.*?` too). Learning regex is hard hehe

Comment: So far this seems to work! At least it displays what I need. Now just to figure out how to write it to a file and I'll be all set I think!

Comment: @DerekB see my last edit, you just need to collect the results of the `foreach` loop in a variable (`$result`) and then `Out-File` the results.

Comment: Hmm - I added the result line and I get an empty file. I am assuming I'm missing something here.

Comment: @DerekB are you sure `(Get-Content ./test.log -Raw)` is pointing to your file?, use the absolute path if in doubt. Also make sure `$result =` is there, before the `foreach`.

Comment: Ah yes I was missing the one $result = line - now it exports to a file - thank you!

Comment: One last question - is there any easy way to export this solution to a comma delimited CSV file?

Comment: @DerekB Yup, I have updated the answer. Doug's answer was covering the export to CSV too

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon when I export it as a CSV I end up with one column with the character count titled "length" - what I really need is 3 columns (first name, last name, ID) with that data in it.

Comment: @DerekB the code as is works perfectly fine for me, you might not be copying as literal as I have posted.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, you were right - one silly mistake was screwing the whole thing up, works perfectly now. Mission accomplished, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using this reusable function:
(See also: [`#16257` String >>>Regex>>> PSCustomObject](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16257))

```
function ConvertFrom-Text {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param (
        [Regex]$Pattern,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeLine = $True)]$InputObject
    )
    process {
        if ($_ -match $pattern) {
            $matches.Remove(0)
            [PSCustomObject]$matches
        }
    }
}
```

```
$log = @(
    'FIRST:BOB LAST:SMITH DOOR:MAIN ENTRANCE ID:123456 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:47 PM INCIDENT:19002304'
    'FIRST:JOHN LAST:DOE DOOR:MAIN ENTRANCE ID:789101 TIME:Friday, December 31, 2021 11:55:47 PM INCIDENT:19002304'
)

$Log |ConvertFrom-Text -Pattern '\bFIRST:(?<First>\S*).*\bLAST:(?<Last>\S*).*\bID:(?<ID>\d+)'

ID     Last  First
--     ----  -----
123456 SMITH BOB
789101 DOE   JOHN
```

Comment: A neat function, but if you're using capture groups there's no need for lookbehinds: `(?<=FIRST:)` would be better as just `FIRST:` etc.